# .net loop through methods in a class

Tags: .net

I've got a Class with an undetermined number of methods inside

```
Public Class MyClass
    Public Sub Foo()
    End Sub

    Public Sub Bar()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Is there an easy way to call all of the methods in "MyClass" without physically specifying each one?  The reason for this is that the methods within "MyClass" are going to be evergrowing, and I don't want to specify the method call for each one when the end goal is to execute every method on a set schedule.

IE: I want to avoid

```
Page_Load
    Foo()
    Bar()
```

### Edit:

I've tried the following code to loop through the methods, but I'm getting an error

```
    Public Shared Sub Calculator()
        Dim methods As New Methods()
        For Each Info As MethodInfo In methods.GetType.GetMethods
            Info.Invoke(Nothing, Nothing)
        Next
    End Sub
```

> System.Reflection.TargetException: Non-static method requires a target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example, invoking methods without parameters:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim FooClass As New someClass()

    For Each method As MethodInfo In FooClass.GetType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance Or
                                                                 BindingFlags.Public Or
                                                                 BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
        Console.WriteLine("Invoking: {0}.{1}()", method.DeclaringType.Name, method.Name)
        method.Invoke(FooClass, Nothing)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried your example and got an error.  I've edited my question above to reflect that. Anything you see that I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I updated my example (and converted it to VB). The first parameter of method.Invoke() needs to be an instance of your class. Does this work for you?

Comment: perfect, that did it.  Thanks.  Just for reference, is using Reflection hard on system resources in any way?  I'm planning on launching this method in a separate worker class, and I'm just wondering about performance hit.

Comment: Your best bet is just to measure it and decide if it's acceptable before considering performance optimizations.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want [Type.GetMethods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d848zkb.aspx) to get a list of the methods, and then use [MethodInfo.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx) to call it.

Though it sounds to me like you're going about this the wrong way. Rather than using reflection to invoke every method on the class, I would suggest you look into delegates and events. That way, the class can *register itself* to get called instead of relying on heuristics to do the calling (for example, what would happen if you added a "helper" method to the `MyClass` class that you *didn't* want to get called?)

As an example, here's how you could use events to do this:

```
class MySchedule
{
    public event EventHandler Fire;

    public void Tick()
    {
        if (Fire != null) {
            Fire(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    public void Register(MySchedule sched)
    {
        sched.Fire += Foo;
        sched.Fire += Bar;
    }

    void Foo(object source, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    void Bar(object source, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

I've used the built-in `EventHandler` delegate, but you can use whatever you like if you want the methods to have a specified signature.

Comment: could you give an example of how you would use delegates in these scenario?

Comment: thank you @codeka.  Can you point me in the right direction for using delegates?

Comment: @rockinthesixstring, @Shawn: I've updated my answer with a quick example.

Comment: so this means that I still have to "register" the event in the register method `sched.Fire += Foo;`.  I think I like the reflection method idea simply for the simplicity.  Add a new method and it will simply run without any further config.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332480(v=VS.71).aspx

I think this is what you are looking for. .NET Reflection allows you to do this very easily.